# How to read files in a junction point directory, using GetFileInformationByHandleEx?

Tags: winapi, ntfs, reparsepoint

I have this code which runs fine if `path` points to a regular directory:

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    wchar_t path[1024] = L"C:\\MyPath\\MyDir";
    
    auto h = CreateFile(path, FILE_LIST_DIRECTORY, FILE_SHARE_READ, NULL, OPEN_EXISTING, FILE_FLAG_BACKUP_SEMANTICS, NULL);
    if (h == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)
    {
        printf("CreateFile error: 0x%08X\n", GetLastError());
        return 0;
    }

    FILE_ID_INFO id = {};
    if (!GetFileInformationByHandleEx(h, FILE_INFO_BY_HANDLE_CLASS::FileIdInfo, &id, sizeof(id)))
    {
        printf("FileIdInfo error: 0x%08X\n", GetLastError());
    }

    unsigned char buffer[4096];
    do
    {
        if (!GetFileInformationByHandleEx(h, FILE_INFO_BY_HANDLE_CLASS::FileIdExtdDirectoryInfo, buffer, ARRAYSIZE(buffer)))
        {
            auto gle = GetLastError();
            if (gle == ERROR_NO_MORE_FILES)
                break;

            printf("FileIdExtdDirectoryInfo error: 0x%08X\n", gle);
            break;
        }

        auto current = buffer;
        do
        {
            auto info = (FILE_ID_EXTD_DIR_INFO*)current;
            wprintf(L"name: %.*s\n", info->FileNameLength / 2, info->FileName);
            if (!info->NextEntryOffset)
                break;

            current += info->NextEntryOffset;
        } while (true);
    } while (true);
    CloseHandle(h);
}
```

But if the directory points to a junction point, it returns (`ERROR_INVALID_PARAMETER` invalid parameter)

```
FileIdInfo error: 0x00000057
FileIdExtdDirectoryInfo error: 0x00000057
```

So, I've tried this for `CreateFile`

```
auto h = CreateFile(path, FILE_LIST_DIRECTORY, FILE_SHARE_READ, NULL, OPEN_EXISTING, FILE_FLAG_BACKUP_SEMANTICS | FILE_FLAG_OPEN_REPARSE_POINT, NULL);
```

and now, I have no error, but it only shows `"."` and `".."` entries, not all the files in the directory which I can read using cmd.exe

```
C:\MyPath\MyDir>dir
 Volume in drive C has no label.
 Volume Serial Number is AEA6-688A

 Directory of C:\MyPath\MyDir

20/10/2017  14:08             (157) My Icon.ico
11/04/2018  09:08               321 My File.cpp
30/04/2018  15:14    <DIR>          My dossier
19/09/2019  10:40          (41 650) New Rich Text Document.rtf
10/10/2021  11:06                 0 New Text Document.txt
               4 File(s)         46 224 bytes
               1 Dir(s)  544 625 274 880 bytes free
```

Comment: this must not be. code must work and for reparse points too. try `RtlGetLastNtStatus()` instead `GetLastError()` - may be this give more info. use `FILE_FLAG_OPEN_REPARSE_POINT` is wrong - in this case will be opened reparse point itself instead folder to which it point

Comment: Ok, since you say it should work (which is in itself an interesting info, also RtlGetLastNtStatus gives back STATUS_INVALID_PARAMETER), I've tested with other junction points (like "C:\Documents and Settings" with MAXIMUM_ALLOWED instead of FILE_LIST_DIRECTORY) and the code works fine. But the cmd.exe command still succeeds where this code fails, so there should be a way to make it work? I want to use GetFileInformationByHandleEx to be able to get FILE_ID_EXTD_DIR_INFO.

Comment: *cmd.exe* used `FindFirstFileEx` or [`NtQueryDirectoryFile`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/ddi/ntifs/nf-ntifs-ntquerydirectoryfile) with [`FileDirectoryInformation`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/ddi/ntifs/ns-ntifs-_file_directory_information) - you can try this too on your junction and look for result. on all junctions which i test - `GetFileInformationByHandleEx` work ok

Comment: @RbMm - I need the Id so I don't think I can use FindFirstFile(Ex), but it seems to work ok with NtQueryDirectoryFile (FileIdFullDirectoryInformation) ... strange...

Comment: @RbMm - More info, NtQueryDirectoryFile  with FileIdExtdDirectoryInformation (not FileIdFullDirectoryInformation) fails with the same STATUS_INVALID_PARAMETER result. So the issue is really about 128-bit object id (which I think is why it works with cmd.exe / FindFirstFileEx, because they don't read that). And in fact the mount point target is a volume that doesn't have the FILE_SUPPORTS_OBJECT_IDS flag, so I guess it all makes sense now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out my code in itself is correct, but it can fail if the file system below doesn't support [NTFS object ID](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/fsutil-objectid), since this is what it's trying to read (using FILE_INFO_BY_HANDLE_CLASS::FileIdInfo and FILE_INFO_BY_HANDLE_CLASS::FileIdExtdDirectoryInfo).

This happens for example if the directory is an NTFS [mount point](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/openspecs/windows_protocols/ms-fscc/ca069dad-ed16-42aa-b057-b6b207f447cc) with a *substitute name* that points to a volume that doesn't have the [FILE_SUPPORTS_OBJECT_IDS](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/fileapi/nf-fileapi-getvolumeinformationw#parameters)  flag set (seen in virtual drive scenarios).

The error here (`ERROR_INVALID_PARAMETER`) is kind of misleading as there's no problem with any parameter (except maybe the `FileInformationClass` one), I would have expected some "unsupported" error instead.

As for cmd.exe, well, it just doesn't read/need that information so it works fine.